# Trying to convert time from 30:30 to 30.5 in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am trying to convert my time watched in a netflix show to a float so I can total it up. I cannot figure out how to convert it. I have tried many ways, including:

```
temp['Minutes'] = temp['Duration'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

```
Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00:54:45'
```

```
2022-05-18 05:21:42 00:54:45 NaN Ozark: Season 4: Mud (Episode 13) NaN Amazon FTVET31DOVI2020 Smart TV00:54:50 00:54:50 US (United States) Wednesday 2022-05-18
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make it clear what you are showing us. See [mre] to understand how to give an example that we can actually use; show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message; and most importantly, *explain what everything is that you're showing to us*. Is the last code box an example of the Dataframe contents? Make sure it is formatted properly, make sure we can see *how it is split into columns*, and show what the `dtype`s are for the columns.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe and the desired output?

Comment: Instead of 00:54:45 I would like 54.75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is convert the seconds that are after the 54 into the percent of the time till 60. This should give you the answer you are looking for assuming your data is consistant

```
data = {
    'time' : ['00:54:45', '00:05:15', '01:32:00', '00:28:00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x : ''.join(x.split(':', 1)[1:]))
df['percent'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x : x.split(':')[1])
df['percent'] = (df['percent'].astype(int) / 60) * 100
df['percent'] = df['percent'].astype(int)
df['final'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(':')[0]) + '.' + df['percent'].astype(str)
df
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: It gets stuck at the 4th line where: df['percent'] = int((df['percent'].astype(int) / 60) * 100)

Comment: What is the error since it works with the provided data from the data variable. You will need to provide more data if it isn't working as expected

Comment: 3 temp['percent'] = temp['Minutes'].apply(lambda x : x.split(':')[1])
----> 4 temp['percent'] = int((temp['percent'].astype(int) / 60) * 100)
      5 temp['final'] = temp['Duration'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split(':')[0]) + ':' + temp['percent'].astype(str)
      6 temp.head(1)

File\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:191, in _coerce_method.<locals>.wrapper(self)
    189 if len(self) == 1:
    190     return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 191 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: I believe you need to add more data to your original post. This error doesn't help a lot, its probably your data is not standardized based on the time variable.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized its being output as a string. I think I can just slice it to grab the pieces?

Comment: I updated my code example. I believe it will resolve the problem

Comment: No problem! If it worked for you don’t forget to make as answered and upvote so others will know it’s completed and see it in their searches as well

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to convert a pd.Series containing strings to a datatype that can be summed up then working with pd.Timedeltas may help here.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
durations = {"Duration": ['00:54:45', '00:05:15', '01:32:00', '00:28:00']}
temp = pd.DataFrame(durations)
```

Converting strings to Timedelta objects:

```
time_deltas = pd.to_timedelta(temp["Duration"])
```

The time_deltas pd.Series can then be summed up and then converted to minutes:

```
minutes = time_deltas.sum().total_seconds() / 60
minutes  # 180.0
```

If you wanted to add the Timedeltas to the existing DataFrame:

```
temp["time_deltas"] = pd.to_timedelta(temp["Duration"])
minutes = temp["time_deltas"].sum().total_seconds() / 60
```